# Get editable rows data in datatables using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to get editable rows data in `datatables`, for example when I clicked the column, then change the data and get value in `datatables`.

I have used this method.

```
editor.on('postEdit', function () {
      debugger;
      oTable = $('#indexList').dataTable();
      var sData = oTable.fnGetData(this.s.editRow);
      console.log(sData[0]);
      alert('The cell clicked on had the value of ' + sData[0]);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will transform clicked TR element to a set of input elements with values from TD tags

```
$(document).on("click", ".data-table tr", function(){
   $(this).find("td").each(function(){
       var st = $(this).text;
       $(this).html ("<input type='text' value='" + str + "'>");
    })
})
```